# k-means clustering in jsfiddle using json data

Tags: json, cluster-analysis, k-means, jsfiddle

I want to make cluster data using K-means using JSON data
The variable to be clustered are "InterestinProgramming", "AbilityinPython",
"AbilityinJS", "AbilityinJAVA", "AbilityinPHP", "AbilityinGolang",
"IhateProgramming" with k scalar 3 that randomly picked from 1st, 11th and 15th.

Comment: my code is here : https://jsfiddle.net/ermadear/379pL4af/3/